# How do I add JS function to dynamically created div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm dynamically creating a table row with a div inside it when the user presses a button. The div has the class "contents."

```
$(document).on("click", ".vote", function() {
        //Deletes selected row
        var rowLoc = this.parentNode.parentNode.rowIndex;
        document.getElementById("news").deleteRow(rowLoc);

        //Adds new row to bottom.
        var table = document.getElementById("news");

        //Adds content to new cell.
        var titleCell = newRow.insertCell(0);
        $(titleCell).addClass("articles");
        titleCell.innerHTML = "<h3><a href='" + articles[index].url + "'>" + articles[index].title + "</a></h3><div class='contents'>" + articles[index].text + "</div>";
        index++;
    });

    document.getElementById("content").innerHTML=output;

    // Adds shorten function to original rows with the div class="contents"
    $(function(){
        $(".contents").shorten();
    });
```

How do I apply `shorten()` to new divs of class "contents"?

Comment: Generally divs and tables don't usually play nicely with each other.

Comment: When using jQuery, use `$('#content').html(output)` instead of `document.getElementById("content").innerHTML=output`.

Answer (score 1):

I'd do it in your on-click handler:

```
var cell = $(titleCell).addClass("articles");
titleCell.innerHTML = ...
cell.find('.contents').shorten();
```

Comment: This broke some of my other code. Does it matter that I have this:
`$.ajaxSetup({ async: false });`

Comment: How did it break your code? I don't think that your ajaxSetup is relevant, but maybe what @mikhailov said could be. Perhaps try `titleCell.html(...)` instead of `titleCell.innerHTML = ...`

Answer (score 0):

innerHTML doesn't update the DOM, so you can use .append() with HTML instead.